# Remove rule from RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have bookmark **ImageButton** with **ALIGN_WITH_PARENT** set to **true** in XML.

If I programatically do (I want to **remove that rule**)

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) bookmark.getLayoutParams(); 
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);
bookmark.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The rule just doesn't apply (in my layout I can see that rule is still active) -> layout isn't good. If I manually do it (some sort of "simulation", set ALIGN WITH PARENT to **false**) in my Layout Editor, my layout is fine which leads to this code up there. Something is wrong.

What?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I believe temporary) Solution is to wrap up that ImageButton in one dummy RelativeLayout and then take the params of that dummy layout and add or remove rules. That way it's working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Insead of calling `setLayoutParams()`, try to use [`requestLayout()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout%28%29) method:

```
bookmark.requestLayout();
```

From API docs:

> Call this when **something has changed which has invalidated the layout of this view**. This will schedule a layout pass of the view tree.

Answer (score 0):

simply call `removeRule()` function on `params`.

for example,

```
params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
```